# Looking for reference for quote

Tags: mathematics, reference-request, quote

In graduate school, I remember hearing or seeing the rough quote:

> Good mathematicians know one branch of math. Great mathematicians
> know two branches.

I'm sure I am somewhat misquoting it, but does anyone have a reference/citation for this quote?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct quote is attributed to Banach: “Good mathematicians see analogies. Great mathematicians see analogies between analogies."

Ulam, S. M. (1976). Adventures of a mathematician. New York

Note: I used Google Books to find this quote with "Good mathematicians" and "Great mathematicians" as search terms.